# How to parse the json url in C ++ and get the title from the source code?

Tags: c++, json, parsing

1. I need to parse json url and the data has a url binding so I need to change "en-us" to "ja-jp" update the value
2. there are two types of url in json data
   I want to change the "articleurl" "en-us" to "ja-jp"
   example:
   http://support.example.com/kb/3159398 → URL is not changed. Getting Japanese title.
   https://support.example.com/en-us/help/40113 → en-US changes to ja-JP. Get title.
3. after update and change i need to add that url title page in my json (title must be in japanese language)
   "urltitle" : 'https://support.example.com/ja-jp/help/40113'
4. the final output will be saved in json format

json url sample data:

```
value = [
    {
      "kbArticles": [
        {
          "articleName": "Release Notes",
          "articleUrl": "https://docs.example.com/en-us/Edge/security",
        }
      ],
      "baseScore": "",
      "temporalScore": "",
    },
    {
      "kbArticles": [
        {
          "articleName": "5006670",
          "articleUrl": "https://support.example.com/help/5006670",
        }
      ],
      "baseScore": "5.5",
      "temporalScore": "4.8",
    }
   ]
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
using namespace web::http;             
using namespace web::http::client;    
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    http_client client("http://api.example.com/");
    http_response response;
    response = client.request(methods::GET, "/get").get();
    std::cout << response.extract_string().get() << "\n";
    response = client.request(methods::GET, "/get").get();
    std::cout << "url: " << response.extract_json().get()[U("url")] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of questions in one. Which one, exactly, are you stuck at and would like help with?

Comment: how to read the JSON data from api with url and change the url language. @Botje